# How to add attribute with if else C#

Tags: c#, attributes, compile-time-constant

I have options to use both SQL Server and PostgresSQL databases. In some classes, I have the following attribute

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
```

used to decorate to class properties:

```
public class MyClass 
{
    #if define PostgresSQL
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    #endif
    public DateTime SysStartTime { get; set; }
}
```

I have this `appsettings.json` file:

```
{
    "Database": {
       "DatabaseType": "PostgresSQL"
    }
}
```

How do I associate the value in `appsettings.json` to the value in `#if define` directive?

Comment: Make a full copy of class, inherit same interface, use a switch in config, use interface instead of class

Comment: you can't, as reading the settings is done at **runtime**, whereas your compiler-switch is evaluated at **compile**-time. But I suppose you read the attribute at runtime anway, so why do you rely on a compile-time-thing in the first place?

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain I guess it may be possible to write my own attribute to 

include ' [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)] 

if the database type is PostgresSQL.

Comment: Can you do the same without using annotations? If you need RDBMS agnostic classes, you can't have DB specific attributes. So I would say if you can outsource this into db specific code.

Comment: Have two set of classes implementing same interfaces. Code the client against interfaces.